# Creating a vector of variables from one vector stored in other

Tags: r

I will just use an example instead of my data.

so, let's say that we have a vector of letters:

```
> LETTERS
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T"
[21] "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

and I create a new vector:

```
vec <- c("A", "D", "H", "Y", "GG")
```

Than I can use such function to see which of letters from `vec` belong to the `LETTERS` instead of TRUE/FALSE.

```
> b <- vec %in% LETTERS
> b
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Is it possible to get a vector of the variables (letters in that case) which were found in the `LETTERS` ?

so the output should be like that:

```
>vec_of_variables
"A", "D", "H", "Y"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific function you might be looking for is `intersect`:

```
> intersect(vec, LETTERS)
[1] "A" "D" "H" "Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do the subsetting with the logical values you just created.

```
vec_of_variables <- vec[vec %in% LETTERS]
```